# Rails App - Seed Data Task - ActiveStorage::IntegrityError - Google Cloud Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, rails-activestorage

I am trying to populate my Rails (version 7.0.7.2) app with some sample data. Attaching items works perfectly in development, testing, and production via a form/UI however I'd like to be able to reset a demo `Project` whenever I need it without much work. However, when I try to run a script to create this data and attach files I receive an `ActiveStorage::IntegrityError` stemming from a `Google::Apis::ClientError`.

I am trying to run this task in development and have my CORS configuration setup per the [Rails documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#example-google-cloud-storage-cors-configuration) but with `localhost` as my origin:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["http://localhost:3000"],
    "method": ["PUT"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Content-MD5", "Content-Disposition"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

I have uploaded several PDFs to the folder `app/assets/files/` and wish to attach these each to an instance of the `Plan` object. Below is the code I've written:

```
sample_project = Project.where(name: "Sample Project").first

sample_project.destroy if sample_project.present?

@address = Address.new(
  street1: "123 Main Street",
  city: "New York",
  region_code: "NY",
  postal_code: "10001",
  country_code: "US"
)

@project = Project.create!(
  name: "Sample Project",
  description: "This is a sample project",
  status: "active",
  address: @address
)

Dir.foreach("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/files/") do |filename|
  if filename != "." && filename != ".."
    puts "Processing #{filename}..."

    @plan = Plan.new(
      project_id: @project.id,
      name: filename,
    )

    filepath = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "files", filename)
    file = File.open(filepath)

    @plan.file.attach(
      io: file,
      filename: filename,
      content_type: "application/pdf"
    )

    file.rewind

    @plan.save!
  end
end
```

The `Project`, `Address`, and `Plan` are all created but on `save!` the Google API returns this error. Unfortunately, the Google API response is very vague and it's unclear to me why it's failing. I also can't seem to find any history of failed file uploads within the Google Cloud Console. Any help is greatly appreciated!